# Magento 2 addFieldToFilter check for NULL not working

Tags: magento2, database, sql, query, addfield

What i am doing

`->addFieldToFilter('value', array(['eq' => '', array('isnull' => true)]))`

What i want in the query - '((`value` = '' )is NULL)`

Can anyone help me on this

Thanks.

Comment: What is your actual requirement ? do you want to check value is empty and null?

Comment: i am checking if a customer ticked the attribute or not when i do null= true doesnt bring me any record but soon as i add is null it works

Comment: so can you explain me what exact you want?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution,

```
->addFieldToFilter('value', array('null' => true) );
```

Comment: this returns (`value` IS NULL) i needed ((`value` = '' )is NULL)

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution,

```
$collection = $objectManager->create('Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Collection');

$collection->addFieldToFilter(
    [
        ['attribute' => 'value', 'null' => true], // Check if 'value' is NULL
        ['attribute' => 'value', 'eq' => '']     // Check if 'value' is empty
    ]
);
```

In the above example, we create a product collection and then use **addFieldToFilter** with an array of filter conditions.

The first condition checks if 'value' is NULL `('null' => true)`, and the second condition checks if 'value' is empty `('eq' => '')`.

These conditions are combined using the OR operator, so the collection will return products where either condition is met.